# Return getString from xml with a string variable?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am newcomer to programming and I am attempting to create an Android app using Android Studio. I've tried searching but my findings do not appear to be what I am looking for, because they seem to be overly complex. What I've written below is just an example.

I want to be able to return a string from string.xml when user types "whale". The string in this case is information about the whale.

This is my java file, animal is already a string entered from a form.

```js
TextView textview = new TextView(this);
String animalType = "water_" + animal; // This become water_whale if user typed whale
String animalInfo = getString(R.string.animalType); // This doesn't work
textView.setText(animalInfo);
```

This is my string.xml

```xml
<string name="water_fish">Fish is a small bla...</string>
<string name="water_whale">A whale is an enourmous blabla...</string>
<string name="land_giraffe">Africa.</string>
```

I have probably tunneled on this particular way and I have probably miss something obvious or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R.string.anyIdentifer` represents an integer value. You can't add your own identifier with it, just the way you can't call any non existent property on any class. If you want to access any resource dynamically with it's name then there is a different approach for that.

Use this

```
TextView textview = new TextView(this);
String animalType = "water_" + animal; 
int animalTypeId = getResources().getIdentifier(animalType, "string", getActivity().getPackageName())
String animalInfo = getResources().getString(animalTypeId);
textView.setText(animalInfo);
```

Comment: It worked, however i did not use `getActivity().getPackageName()` as it gave me errors, but when using only  `getPackageName()` I got the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`String string=getResources().getString(R.string.water_whale);`

you can't use `getString()` method directly.